# Como alinhar um button verticalmente em uma row

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html5

Não estou conseguindo alinhar verticalmente um button dentro de uma row. Já tentei inserir um label para forçá-lo para baixo, mas ele nem se move.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
  input[type="text"], select {
        /*font-size: 13px;*/
    }
    
    .selectClass {
        /*font-size: 13px;*/
    }
    
    label {
        /*font-size: 13px;*/
        /*color:#808080;*/
    }
    
    form label {
        font-weight:normal;
    }
    
    input[type=text] {
        width: 100%;
        /*padding: 12px 20px;*/
        /*margin: 8px 0;*/
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /*border: 1px solid #555;*/
        outline: none;
    }
    
    input[type=text]:focus {
        background-color: lightblue;
        color:black;
    }
    
    textarea:focus {
        background-color: lightblue;
        color: black;
    }
    
    /*.distanciaForms div[class^="col-"] {*/
        /*padding: calc(15px / 2);*/ /* calcula a distancia entro um inpute e outro e os cantos da tela*/
    /*}*/
    
    .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 1% !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btn-add-contato">Novo contato</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="div-contatos">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].ContatoTipoId" class="control-label">Tipo de Contato</label>
                            <select name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].ContatoTipoId" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].Contato" class="control-label">Contato</label>
                            <input type="text" name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].Contato" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                            <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].ContatoPrincipal" checked
                                       autocomplete="off" />
                                <label for="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].ContatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].Detalhes" class="control-label">Detalhes</label>
                            <textarea name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].Detalhes" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-remover-contato">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Existe uma maneira de alinhá-lo verticalmente de forma fácil?

Comment: Já tentou utilizando o `padding` como eu falei na outra pergunta que vc fez do checkbos?

Comment: Tentei... No outro post ficou um pouco desalinhado o checkbox, aí deu certo fazer usando um label quebrando o conteúdo. Com o button, não funcionou... Ficou desalinhado.

Comment: Cara eu dei um   `margin-top: 30px` no `<button>` e ficou praticamente 100% alinhado. Mas pode ser que 30px não fique exatamente alinhando com esse modelo que vc está usando, ai vc ajusta esse valor para ficar certinho. Testa ai

Comment: Funcionou @hugocsl ...Antes, eu testei o padding no bloco da row. Acho que não deu certo por isso! Obrigado!

Comment: Legal que resolveu, mas pq vc marcou como aceita a resposta que não deu certo?

Comment: Legal que resolveu, mas pq vc marcou como aceita a resposta que não deu certo?

Comment: A resposta deu certo, pq a classe alinha o elemento no meio da row e nao em relaçao aos outros elementos. O que precisa ainda eh trazer o botao um pouco mais pra baixo, ou seja, abaixo do centro. Basta usar top e position relative.

Comment: Ela deu certo com os demais itens. Só o button que não funcionava...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como BS3 já alinharia automaticamente, você deve estar usando BS4. Adicione a classe `align-items-center` na div-pai dos campos:

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
```

Como o BS4 trabalha com flexbox, irá alinhar os elementos no centro verticalmente. E não precisa do `label` vazio que colocou.

```css
input[type="text"], select {
        /*font-size: 13px;*/
    }
    
    .selectClass {
        /*font-size: 13px;*/
    }
    
    label {
        /*font-size: 13px;*/
        /*color:#808080;*/
    }
    
    form label {
        font-weight:normal;
    }
    
    input[type=text] {
        width: 100%;
        /*padding: 12px 20px;*/
        /*margin: 8px 0;*/
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /*border: 1px solid #555;*/
        outline: none;
    }
    
    input[type=text]:focus {
        background-color: lightblue;
        color:black;
    }
    
    textarea:focus {
        background-color: lightblue;
        color: black;
    }
    
    /*.distanciaForms div[class^="col-"] {*/
        /*padding: calc(15px / 2);*/ /* calcula a distancia entro um inpute e outro e os cantos da tela*/
    /*}*/
    
    .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 1% !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="btn-add-contato">Novo contato</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="div-contatos">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].ContatoTipoId" class="control-label">Tipo de Contato</label>
                            <select name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].ContatoTipoId" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].Contato" class="control-label">Contato</label>
                            <input type="text" name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].Contato" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
                            <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].ContatoPrincipal" checked autocomplete="off" />
                                <label for="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].ContatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].Detalhes" class="control-label">Detalhes</label>
                            <textarea name="PessoaContatoViewModel[0].Detalhes" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-remover-contato alinha-vert">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Lixo</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O button parece estar alinhado mais para cima em relação aos demais objetos.... Ele tinha que descer um pouco mais... Eu ajeitei o checkbox usando um label de quebra, mas o button é o único que ficou mais ara cima...

Comment: O companheiro @ hugocsl  resolveu!! Obrigado aos dois pela força!

Comment: Cara, a classe que falei irá alinhar o botão no meio da row. O que vc pode fazer além disso é ajustar a posição um pouco mais para baixo com top: 10px; position: relative; Aí vc ajusta o 10px até ficar do jeito que quer.